# Uncaught reference error: slider is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I'm trying to implement [joss benner's fix as shown here](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/334). I need to implement this code:

```
slider.setOpts = function(opts) {
  for (var opt in opts) {
    vars[opt] = opts[opt];
  }
  slider.setup();
}

slider.getOpts = function() {
  return vars;
}
```

I've [tried with this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BSwJn/125/), but I just get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: slider is not defined
```

in the console. Not really what I'm doing. The other commenters seem to be able to implement it no problem.

Could someone also explain the meaning behind the code... what is `slider`? A class? A function? Where should I place the above code to add the `.setOpts` function?

Comment: That code is a fix that is added to the flexslider core.

Comment: Oh..that would make sense..

Comment: You'd add it here https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js

Comment: I see now..feel like an idiot. Thanks v much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He wrote

> I added these public methods to flexslider

To do so, you have to add those lines of code inside the `jquery.flexslider.js`-file and not in another js-file as you did in the fiddle. The error tells you what the problem is. And in your case, `slider` is in fact not defined, because the `slider`-variable is being declared inside a codeblock of the `jquery.flexslider.js` which means, there is no reference to this variable outside of this block.

The public methods start in line 426, so add your code there.